# How to dynamically create a grid in WPF?

Tags: wpf

I want to create a `Grid` dynamically to show product information like any e-commerce site.

I am fetching product information from JSON and then want to show each product details to tiles like view.

Comment: DataGrid ? or a single Object with the product details, placed properly in a Grid ?

Comment: I thought of creating New object for every product or is there any way to fill datagrid from JSON data source?

Comment: I'm a bit unclear about what your desired layout is. Can you draw a quick mockup of it in something like [balsamiq](http://webdemo.balsamiq.com/) to describe further? Also can you clarify if you need selection behavior, column headers, or editing templates? If you don't need all or some of those features, an alternate control with a custom template may be a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using loads of code-behind code, my suggestion is using an `ItemsControl` with a `WrapPanel` inside.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Products}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- Your item template -->
            <Grid Height="120" Width="70">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding ProductName}" />
                <Image Grid.Row="1" Source="{Binding Thumbnail}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Description}" />
            </Grid>
            <!-- Your item template -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

`Products` would be a collection of items in your DataContext (ViewModel, if you're using MVVM), and you just have to bind to the properties of those items in the Item Template (like `ProductName`, `Thumbnail` or `Description` in my example).

Pros:

- Less code
- 100% XAML
- Adapts itself to the available space
- Can be easily configured for horizontal or vertical, or left-to-right or right-to-left layouts

Cons:

- No selection
- No headers
- No editable templates
- Mmmh, it's not a Grid?

If you want all the fancy functionalities, like headers, selection, etc., you'll have to use something like a DataGrid, but then you lose the tiled layout.

Comment: I would also recommend an ItemsControl, however it should be noted it doesn't support the same functionality as a DataGrid such as Selection behavior, Column Headers, Editing Templates, etc. If those features are not needed, I would definitely use an ItemsControl

Comment: Yup, you're right. But the OP was asking for a `Grid`, and since he also mentioned " e-commerce sites", I guessed he just wanted to show items in a tiled layout. I'll add those cons to my answer, though :P